# ASP Session variables and array assignments

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, session-variables

I have a question about session variables and array assignments.

I have a two dimensional array with 10 rows and 20 columns.  Then example 1 does not work and example 2 works:

Example 1:

```
session('anAr')(5, 10) = 'ab'
response.Write '<br>The new value is ' & session('anAr')(5, 10)
```

The new value of session('anAr')(5, 10) is printed as empty string.

Example 2:

```
dim localAr: localAr = session('anAr')
locarAr(0)(5, 10) = 'abc'
session('anAr') = localAr
response.Write '<br>The new value is ' & session('anAr')(5, 10)
```

Now the update to session ('anAr')(5, 10) has been done.

Although it works, I think the problem is that all the `session('anAr')` is first copied to the localAr and then all the localAr is copied to the `session('anAr')`.

Could an expert tell me please if there is any way to modify the `session('anAr')(5, 10)` without copying of the session array to a local array?

Comment: mAn, in your first sample you store date in session variable `anA` but read data from session variable `anAr`.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand what you want to tell me. Can you elaborate it pleas?

Comment: `session('anA')(5, 10) = 'ab'` -- you are saving data (value) in session variable with name `anA`, right? but in next line you are trying to read data (value) from session variable with name `anAr`. you see, you are reading data from *different* variable.

Comment: in other words: change `session('anA')(5, 10) = 'ab'` to `session('anAr')(5, 10) = 'ab' ` for your first sample

Comment: Oh I am sorry that this was only a misprint in my question. I am always considering anAr and array name. If you test the example with only anAr name you know what I mean.

Comment: Has anyone an expert response to my question?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunetaly there's not. You have to use local arrays.

From [Session Object (IIS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524319(v=vs.90).aspx)

> If you store an array in a Session object, **you should not attempt to
>   alter the elements of the stored array directly**. For example, the
>   following script does not work:
>
> `<% Session("StoredArray")(3) = "new value" %>`
>
> The preceding script does not work because the Session object is
>   implemented as a collection. The array element StoredArray(3) does not
>   receive the new value. Instead, the value is indexed into the
>   collection, overwriting any information stored at that location.
>
> **It is strongly recommended that if you store an array in the Session
>   object, you retrieve a copy of the array before retrieving or changing
>   any of the elements of the array.** When you are finished using the
>   array, you should store the array in the Session object again, so that
>   any changes you made are saved, as demonstrated in the following
>   example:

```vb
<% 
'Creating and initializing the array 
Dim MyArray() 
Redim MyArray(5) 
MyArray(0) = "hello" 
MyArray(1) = "some other string" 

'Storing the array in the Session object. 
Session("StoredArray") = MyArray 

Response.Redirect("file2.asp") 
%>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The information you wrote me is what was I  my question and I hoped for a way out of it. But unfortunately as you wrote there is no solution to the problem other than the resource taking copying of the session array in a local array.